# Build error on Azue AKS based Build agents for Azuredevops

Tags: azure-devops, ubuntu-18.04, azure-aks, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

AzureDevops Build agents in AKS (Ubuntu based) throwing unexpected eror while executing any tasks in them as below.
below are the configuration Files which we used.

DockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# To make it easier for build and release pipelines to run apt-get,
# configure apt to not require confirmation (assume the -y argument by default)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    jq \
    git \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -LsS https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Can be 'linux-x64', 'linux-arm64', 'linux-arm', 'rhel.6-x64'.
ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```

AKS Deployment File

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azdevops-deployment
  labels:
    app: azdevops-agent
spec:
  replicas: 1 #here is the configuration for the actual agent always running
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: azdevops-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azdevops-agent
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubepodcreation
        image: customised and built docker image
        env:
          - name: AZP_URL
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azdevops
                key: AZP_URL
          - name: AZP_TOKEN
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azdevops
                key: AZP_TOKEN
          - name: AZP_POOL
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azdevops
                key: AZP_POOL
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
          name: docker-volume
      volumes:
      - name: docker-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

We were able to successfully add the deployment to Azuredevops Agent pool and could execute the pipeline on them. But Its throwing strange error related to dynatrace for all the tasks which is getting executed inside them..

```
/opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.251.xxxxxxxxxx/any/nodejs/nodejsagent.js:2611
  const e = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8), d = 2 ** 32;
                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at module.js:676:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/azp/externals/node/bin/node', arguments '"/azp/_work/_tasks/PublishBuildArtifacts_2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe/1.158.3/publishbuildartifacts.js"'.
```

Comment: We would need to run the agent pods in nodes where dynatrace is not enabled or need to upgrade node version as dynatrace is using old node versions

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)